# heap destruction of classes and globals

Tags: c++, destructor, heap-memory, stdmap

When the program ends does the items in the heap are destroyed by order?

What could be the result of the following scenario:

1. create class a1,
   class a1 contains static std::map
2. create class b1, b1 destructor print the map content
3. insert data to map

   ```
   std::string mapkey = "abcd";
   map.insert(make_pair(mapkey,20));
   ```
4. exit program

In case class b1 destructor prints the value of 'mapkey', is it possible that map key string will be destroyed before class b since it was created after class b1? and therefore cause a core dump (since '\0' will is not at the end of the array)?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] that shows how everything is stored and shared?

Comment: Memory leaks are generally not an issue during program exit, because all memory allocated by the program will be reclaimed by the OS when the program exits.

Comment: It is much easier to understand and reason about *actual code* than it is English descriptions of code. There is much less room for misinterpretation. Consider editing such a sample into your question.

Comment: The question and your example don't seem to be a good fit at all. The only heap-managed object we have any degree of confidence in the scenario you presented is the key/value pair inserted into your map's ordered association container, and it is owned by the static map instance. Your map object itself is not heap-managed (it is class-static). And  both the `a1` and `b1` instances (which, for some reason, you seem to be using synonymously with class names; not instances) have no description provided for their memory management provided. Put a **complete** sample in your question please.

Answer (score 1):

The standard says:

> 3.7.3
>
> Dynamic storage duration [basic.stc.dynamic]
>
> > 1 Objects can be created dynamically during program execution (1.9),
> >     using newexpressions (5.3.4), and destroyed using deleteexpressions
> >     (5.3.5).

What this means is that at the termination of your program, any object allocated with `new` that your program has not released with `delete` will still be extant and no attempt to destroy it or its members will be made. The object and all of its members will be 'leaked'. Most operating systems will simply reclaim the lost memory once the process is ended, but again, they won't c++-destroy the objects represented there.

Example:

```
#include <map>

struct A {
    std::map<int, int> m;
    int i;
};

int main() {
    A a1;  // cleaned up on scope exit
    A* a2 = new A;  // pointer lost on scope exit -- leak
}
```

Because we don't `delete` a2, neither the class nor any of its members are destroyed, all of the memory used by a2 and its members remains allocated until the operating system reclaims the processes memory.

You can leverage [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to manage this, indeed C++11 and beyond provide "smart pointers" to handle this. Basically, a smart pointer is an object wrapper around a pointer; when the object goes out of scope it is destructed, and the [default] destructor frees the pointer:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    std::map<int, int> m;
    int i;
};

int main() {
    A a1;  // concreate instance: destructed on scope exit
    std::unique_ptr<A> a2 = std::make_unique<A>();
    // a2 is a concrete instance of a unique_ptr, so is destructed on scope exit
    // and it's destructor will delete the object pointed to for us.
}
```

`unique_ptr`s have very minimal overhead, they are pretty much just a pointer with a wrapper that knows when it goes out of scope it needs to call it's objects' destructor for you.

In the above example, we could have shorted our `unique_ptr`s definition to:

```
    auto a2 = std::make_unique<A>();
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the program ends does the items in the heap are destroyed by order?

No. Objects that have dynamic storage (i.e. objects that are stored "on the heap") are not destroyed when the program ends. They are destroyed when `delete` is called on the pointer that points to the object. That happens before the program has ended, unless the pointer was leaked. If the pointer had leaked, then the object will not be destroyed at all.

Comment: ...and there is no memory leaks as all memory is reclaimed by OS on process termination.

Comment: is it reasonable that the std::string that is stored in map (as key) will be released before  other classes?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: This is wrong for two reasons: `1` The assumption that **every** OS in this galaxy would reclaim memory on process termination does not hold. `2` It still is a memory leak, and no matter how much you try, eventually your garbage collection will no longer succeed in simulating a computer with an infinite amount of memory.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès usually. But there has been [exceptions to that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminate_and_stay_resident_program).

Comment: @15412s classes are not stored in memory and are not freed. As such, I don't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: Alright then, call it heap. Not the correct term. C++ does not mention heap memory. It does mention *freestore*, though.

Comment: @IInspectable if OP asks about objects on heap, it's quite possible that they won't understand when one answers about objects in the freestore. Dynamic storage (duration) is a correct term used by the standard, and the parenthesized addition is for OP's (and other confused beginner's) benefit so that they understand the connection. If you feel that the difference between heap and free store should be explained in this answer, feel free to add explanation (I appreciate), but please don't leave out the connection to the heap that OP asked about.

Comment: @IInspectable and user2079303 I doubt OP was thinking about such OSes, but you're formally right in point 1. Don't understand your point 2, is it subsumed by point 1? or? I mean if memory is reclaimed by OS then there is a leak from the application logic viewpoint, but no from the OS. If memory is not reclaimed, then there is an OS leak.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: You are arguing, that a shot doesn't make a noise, unless someone is listening. While entertaining, what you put forth is not what differentiates a memory leak from a program that doesn't leak resources. Of course, these are all just artifacts of systems trying to simulate an infinite amount of memory on memory constrained devices.